# Сгруппировать записи по разности значений в столбце

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть записи в БД time series

```
id  time    
1   100
2   101
3   102
4   103
5   110
6   111
7   112
8   113
```

Нужно написать такой запрос, который бы сгруппировал строки по не превышаюшие разность time в 1, то есть в данном примере бы плоулиось

```
ids     times
1,2,3,4 100,101,102,103
5,6,7   110,111,112
8       113
```

Comment: А почему значение 113 вывалилось в отдельную группу?

Answer (score 3):

```
select string_agg(id::text,','), string_agg(time::text,',')
  from (
    select id, time, sum(grp_change) over(order by time) grp
      from (
        select id, time, case when coalesce(time-lag(time) over(order by time), 0) <= 1 then 0 else 1 end grp_change
          from test
      ) x
  ) y
group by grp
```

В подзапросе *x* выставляем 1 у записей с разрывом во времени более 1, у остальных 0. Подзапрос *y* суммирует эти признаки, таким образом получая номера групп. Внешнему запросу остается только сгруппировать по готовому номеру группы.

[Пример на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a5ddc/1)